# SQLDeveloper not reading my *.conf file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer does not seems to be reading my *.conf file ( location below ).

```
C:\app\client\myname\product\12.2.0\client_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf
```

The reason I say that is the following line in the `*.conf` file does not generates an error - no matter whatever value I put:

```
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=XXXX
```

Comment: Hi, when you start SQL Developer, can you check `Help>about` and select the `Properties` tab  From there, peruse the properties of your installation. Do you see references to this path?

Comment: Which Property (Name) should I look for ?

Comment: `ide.conf` and `ide.config_path_name` should show the `sqldeveloper.conf` file path being used.

Comment: JVM options need to go in the product.conf file, you'll see that in your user $HOME dir, in a .sqldeveloper subdir